# How can I determine the input size of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis

Could you explain to me the input size of the algorithm with these cases? I can't understand the cases with multiple input parameters. Thanks.

```
algorithm_1( a[1,...,n], b[1,...,n] )
    for i ← 1 to legth[a] step ​1 do
        for j ← 1 to legth[b] step ​1 do
            x++
    return 0
```

-

```
algorithm_2( a[1,...,n], b[1,...,n] )
    return 1
```

-

```
algorithm_3( a[1,...,n], n )
    for i ← 0 to n step ​1 do
        sum += a[i]
    return sum
```

-

```
algorithm_4( m, n )
    for i ← 0 to n step ​1 do
        sum += m*2
    return sum
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. How $A$ and $B$ are given?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? The input size is the size of the input. "Size" means size and "input" means input so it's hard to see what you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first code segment, input size is 2n. a has n elements, so does b.

for the second code segment, input size is 2n. a has n elements, so does b.

for the third segment, input size is n+1. a has n elements, and there is another value n.

for the fourth code segment, input size is 2.

Comment: This might not be accurate depending on the computation model and the nature of the input arrays, as each element in these arrays might require more than one bit to encode.

Comment: @Tassle: a good thing user127490 mostly used elements as a unit of input size, never mentioning bits.

Comment: @greybeard I'm just saying this to warn the asker and other people who might read this answer, as generally (in my experience) input size refers to the size of the encoded input.  This sometimes leads to confusion about what does or doesn't constitute a poly-time algorithm for example.